# Grouping column data in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda data frame (df) with many columns. For the sake of simplicity, I am posting three columns with dummy data here.

```
Timestamp    Source    Length
0            1              5
1            1              5
2            1              5
3            2              5
4            2              5
5            3              5
6            1              5
7            3              5
8            2              5
9            1              5
```

Using Panda functions, First I set timestamp as index of the df.

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data[data.columns[1]]*10**9) # Convert timestamp
df = df.set_index(index) # Set Timestamp as index
```

Next I can use **groupby** and **pd.TimeGrouper** functions to group the data into 5 seconds bins and compute cumulative length for each bin as following:

```
df_length = data[data.columns[5]].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5S')).sum()
```

So the **df_length** dataframe should look like:

```
Timestamp     Length
0             25
5             25
```

Now the problem is: "I want to get the same bins of 5 seconds, but ant to compute the cumulative length for each source (1,2 and 3) in separate columns in the following format:

```
Timestamp    1     2     3
0            15    10    0
5            10    5     10
```

I think I can use df.groupby with some conditions to get it. But confused and tired now :(

> Appreciate solution using panda functions only.

Comment: Your "dummy data" does not have 5 columns, so your `df_length` function will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new column for groupby `Source` for `MultiIndex DataFrame` and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) last level of `MultiIndex` for columns:

```
print (df[df.columns[2]].groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('5S'), df['Source']]).sum())
Timestamp            Source
1970-01-01 00:00:00  1         15
                     2         10
1970-01-01 00:00:05  1         10
                     2          5
                     3         10
Name: Length, dtype: int64

df1 = df[df.columns[2]].groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('5S'), df['Source']])
                       .sum()
                       .unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Source                1   2   3
Timestamp                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00  15  10   0
1970-01-01 00:00:05  10   5  10
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using a pivot table but this is much better. Nice work!

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! However would you please explain the code, how it works because I might face some other similar kind of grouping problems with my data.